# Error: This endpoint has been deprecated

Tags: iphone, facebook, sdk, oauth

My app has is no longer allowing people to post to facebook from it, and it is throwing this error when I try -

"Error: This endpoint has been deprecated. To temporarily enable it, you may disable the "august 2012" platform migration. It will be disabled permanently on August 1, 2012."

I read a couple of other posts from people having the same issue, and attempted to fix it, by disabling August 2012 Breaking Changes. It was already disabled though, and I have been unable to find any other way to fix the problem.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: [StackOverflow is not a proxy for Customer Support](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128579/172661). This is a question that most likely should be asked at Facebook, as it does not appear to be a programming question.

Comment: You haven't put anywhere near enough information here for us to help you; what API call are you making? Does Facebook's [Roadmap](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/) mention that the method is deprecated or scheduled for removal? Have you tried updating the code to use the newest APIs?

Comment: I am having the same problem now, will update Sharekit to 2.0 will help?

Comment: Seems like this is an issue in Sharekit?

Comment: Ya i also got the same error in share kit...any solution guys???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Facebook make changes to their API, they're [offering a migration period of 90 days](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/change-policy/) for the developers to [migrate](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/migrations/).

But if you haven't migrated after that grace period, you're pretty much screwed.

These are the [breaking changes from August 2012](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/):

> **Disabling FB.Canvas.setAutoResize** - Originally scheduled for January
>   1, 2011  We have renamed FB.Canvas.setAutoResize to
>   FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow so that the method more accurately represents
>   its function. FB.Canvas.setAutoResize will stop working on August 1st.
>   We will completely delete the function on September 5th.
>
> **Page Post GETs from Graph API/FQL Will Require an Access Token**
>   All calls to GET Page posts from the Graph API or FQL will now require an
>   access token to be used.
>
> **Removing prompt_permissions.php and prompt_feed.php** 
>   We will be removing a very old version of the feed dialog
>   (/connect/prompt_feed.php) as well as a very old version of the auth
>   dialog (/connect/prompt_permissions(s).php). If you are one of the
>   very few developers still using these legacy endpoints, you should
>   upgrade to the current Feed Dialog and/or OAuth Dialog.
>
> **Removing Add To Timeline Plugin**
>   We will be removing the Add to
>   Timeline plugin. If you are embedding the Add to Timeline plugin, we
>   will render the Login Button in its place with the publish_actions
>   permission automatically added to the scope parameter.

I can't tell which change that broke your app (though I'm guessing it's **Removing prompt_permissions.php and prompt_feed.php**), but you should make sure to update to the latest version of any Facebook framework (i.e. [update ShareKit](http://getsharekit.com/install/#download)) you're using and/or make sure to use the new Facebook API ASAP.

To avoid similar issues in the future, be sure to watch the [roadmap](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/) and - even better - follow [the developer blog](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/).